# Since there is an axial tilt present on planets, does this also affect their orbital angular momentum?

Tags: orbit, astrophysics, axial-tilt

I would like to know whether an axial tilt on planets will affect their orbital angular momentum since I am creating a homework regarding angular momenta of planetary bodies in the Solar System.

Comment: Why do you think the axial tilt should (or should not) affect the orbital angular momentum?

Answer (score 1):

Well according to this [website](https://link.springer.com/10.1007%2F1-4020-4520-4_10):

> There are two contributions to the Earth's angular momentum: the spin angular momentum of rotation about an axis through its center of mass, and its orbital angular momentum about the Sun or mass center of the solar system.

The axial tilt probably doesn't affect the angular momentum. Since the equation for specific relative angular momentum is:

[image]

where $v$ is the velocity vector, $h$ is the specific relative angular momentum and [image: r] is the is the position vector from $m_1$ to $m_2$ with scalar magnitude $r$.

Here's more information on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_angular_momentum).